# retrieving the result set from search bar while clearing the data

Tags: angular

Suppose we enter the searching data like 5. If it's matching then it'll show the result set but if we enter 56 we get the error message "no data found".

**But when we clear the first value 6 and then my function is not searching for the input 5.**

How to fix this issue?

My code is available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rlf3nz

listuser.component.ts

```
SearchById(id) {
    if ( id === '' || id === null || id === undefined) {
      this.users = this.defaultUsers.slice();
      if ( this.users.length > 0 ) {
        this.isTableResult = true;
      }       
    } else {
      id = parseInt(id);
      this.users = this.users.filter(x => x.id === id);
      if ( this.users.length > 0 ) {
        this.isTableResult = true;
      } else {
        this.isTableResult = false;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each time you are using the filter you are manipulating what it is in the array so it is removing it and never replacing it. Try making a replica of the data and manipulating that when searching for users by id, each the the function is called. e. let users = this.users. Then manipulate users.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `this.users` array every time you are filtering. You need to create a copy of the array with the filtered results, let's say `this.filteredUsers`

```
if ( id === '' || id === null || id === undefined) {
   this.filteredUsers = this.users.slice();
} else {
   id = parseInt(id);
   this.filteredUsers = this.users.filter(x => x.id === id); 
   ...
}
```

Don't forget to initialize `this.filteredUsers` to be equal to `this.users.slice()` in the `ngOnInit()` function as soon as the data is available:

```
this.filteredUsers = this.users.slice();
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syqneh

Since you are importing the data from an API, you both have to set the `this.filteredUsers` and `this.users` equal to the API response

```
this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((response) => { 
    this.filteredUsers = this.users = response.slice(); 

}
```

Comment: This code is working here in stackblitz  but in my code i'm retrieving the values from my api. So i have written: private users: User[] = []; .To show the sample data i have given some dummy values in the Data Grid. By replacing your code I'm not able to perform the search operation.

Comment: Yes, you have to initialize the `filteredUsers` as soon as you receive the data back from the API, so within the 
   `this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((users) => {
         this.filteredUsers = this.users.slice();
    }`

Comment: No brother it's not working in my local machine with API. It's not searching for the result itself. Just it's showing the log with 2 arrays.

Comment: @AVINASHM Did it fix your problem in the end?

Comment: No it's not working !!  In your stackblitz link it's working but when i tried to retrieve the value from my API with your result the search operation is not fetching the resultant data

Comment: Did you follow the last bit of advice? 

Since you are importing the data from an API, you both have to set the `this.filteredUsers` and `this.users` equal to the API response

`this._userService.getUsers().subscribe((response) => { 
    this.filteredUsers = this.users = response.slice(); 
}`

Comment: It would be nice if you would mark the answer as accepted. It solved the stackblitz problem. I also proposed how to solve it with the API.